# Koa-pg Can't find module pg

Tags: node.js, postgresql, koa

Hey so I'm trying to get Nodejs Koa to talk to postgres using the Koa-pg module, but I keep getting a 'Can't find module pg' error. 
I've tried to follow the koa-pg examples, but have come up short...so any advice would on how to progress would be appreciated.

If created my app.js file as follows:

```
var koa = require('koa');
var route = require('koa-route');
var koaPg = require('koa-pg');
var roads = require('./controllers/roads');
var app = module.exports = koa();

app.use(route.get('/roads/bbox/', roads.bbox));

app.listen(3000);
console.log('listening on port 3000');
```

And then created my controller file as follows:

```
var credentials = require('../credentials.js');
var environment = credentials.dev;

app.use(koaPg('postgres://' + environment.user + '@' + environment.host + ':' + environment.port + '/' + environment.database))

module.exports.bbox = function * bbox(next) {
  var result = yield this.koaPg.db.client.queryPromise('SELECT now()')
  console.log('result: ', result)

  this.body = result.rows[0].now.toISOString()
};
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'pg'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\User\Documents\restful_koa\node_modul
es\koa-pg\index.js:12:27)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
```

This is only a personal project but I'd love to understand where i'm going wrong.
Cheers

Comment: You still need to install the `pg` module (`npm install pg`), `koa-pg` is just a wrapper.

Comment: `koa-pg` has `co-pg` as a dependency so when you install the former the latter is also installed. But `pg` is not a dependency of `co-pg` and that is why you have to install it separately. @BenFortune you should probably just make your comment into an answer since there isn't really anything else to add.

Comment: @PeadarDoyle I'll let you, since you explained it better than I did. :)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments:

You need to install the `pg` module via `npm install pg` or `npm install pg --save` if you want to save it to `package.json`.

The reason you need to do this is `koa-pg` has `co-pg` as a dependency so when you install the former the latter is also installed. But `pg` is not a dependency of `co-pg` and that is why you have to install it separately.

Comment: Ah brilliant...I could see co-pg was a dependency, and assumed all other dependencies would have been included. I've installed pg and my server is running, although calling my route causes th server to fall over...but thats a different story.